# Как организовать огромную таблицу на странице клиента?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vue.js, knockoutjs

Имеется таблица в 40 столбцов и несколько тысяч строк.
Допустим что выводится некоторая информация по странам, нажимая на страну появляются строки областей, а нажимая на область - города.
Я выгрузил данные на страницу. И вроде бы все хорошо, но имеются еще и фильтры. Нужно считать население только тех городов, в которых проживает больше 300.000 человек. 
Постоянное обращение к базе будет очень тормозить, потому что на вывод данных уходит 7 секунд.
Как мне отфильтровать данные прямо на странице? Слышал, что есть фреймворки типа Vue.js, Knockout.js помогут ли они мне в этом? Или просто создать JS объект и работать уже с ним? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: 1) Если вам надо фильтровать большой набор данных, используйте БД и настраивайте индексы в ней 2) Если у вас получается очень много результатов, то нет смысла их выводить все, используйте постраничный вывод

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов много, вы сами несколько перечислили. Все зависит от ваших требований. Если у вас есть время, можете изучить и использовать клиентский mvc (Angular, React, Vue). Можете также использовать серверный кэш (Redis). Или как вы сами описали создать js объект. Можно попытаться оптимизировать базу данных, может быть добавить какой нибудь индекс.

Comment: Подскажите, страница будет работать быстрее через JS объект или Vue.js объект?

Comment: Вы задаете очень абстрактные вопросы. То, как страница будет работать через js объект зависит только от вас, вы всю обработку берете на себя. Если вы реализуете это лучше чем разработчики Vue, то конечно будет работать быстрее. Я не специалист по Vue, но может быть у них функционал более широкий, чем вам необходимо, а вы сами реализуете только необходимое, тогда опять таки возможно будет работать быстрее.

Comment: понял, спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего изначально присылать фильтрованные данные из БД, затем сделать пагинацию, выводящую по 10 вариантов, например.

[Вот пример того, как она делается, с использованием vue.js](https://medium.com/@denny.headrick/pagination-in-vue-js-4bfce47e573b)